# Is there a way to ascertain the origin of text given to a TextInput component?

Tags: react-native

We are working on an application where we want users to only provide input to our application with their voice, but only want the text transcription of it. If we have a TextInput component, and ask the user to use voice recognition, rather than typing on their keyboard, is there a way to see if they actually used the system's inherent voice recognition?

Comment: I hope this could help https://github.com/react-native-community/voice

Comment: We are using that but integrating it into GiftedChat is proving rather challenging.